# Display User's Django Rest Framework Auth token in templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I recently implemented Django Rest Framework into my project, and I was wondering if it is possible for me to display the Token that has the associated User object attached to it.

So if I, for example could do this in the templates: {{ user.token }}.

Answer (score 1):

You can write middleware
For example:

```
class GetUsrTokenMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
FORWARDED_FOR_FIELDS = [
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST',
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER',
]

def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        if request.user.is_authenticate():
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
            setattr(request.user,'token',token.key)
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display the token using templates `{% csrf_token %}`

and Python code as well using `get_token(request)`.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/